# Meteor for Windows in WebStorm

Tags: meteor

I am learning how to use Meteor in Windows (just installed the preview released last week).  I'm using WebStorm

I ran through the instructions on page 1 of this tutorial (https://www.meteor.com/try) and can see the fully rendered website at http://localhost:3000.  However, when I follow the instructions and paste the code directly from page 2 (https://www.meteor.com/try/2), the website does not load properly.  The code is:

```
<!-- simple-todos.html -->
<head>
  <title>Todo List</title>
</head>

<body>
  <div class="container">
    <header>
      <h1>Todo List</h1>
    </header>

    <ul>
      {{#each tasks}}
        {{> task}}
      {{/each}}
    </ul>
  </div>
</body>

<template name="task">
  <li>{{text}}</li>
</template>

// simple-todos.js
if (Meteor.isClient) {
  // This code only runs on the client
  Template.body.helpers({
    tasks: [
      { text: "This is task 1" },
      { text: "This is task 2" },
      { text: "This is task 3" }
    ]
  });
}
```

The instructions say I should see:

Todo List
This is task 1
This is task 2
This is task 3

Instead, I see:

Todo List
{{#each tasks}} {{> task}} {{/each}}

Somehow the Meteor code is not being recognized.  Am I missing a step?  I thought it might have something to do with the Windows release, but the first case loaded fine.

Thank you.

Brendan

Comment: Showing my inexperience here, didn't realize I needed to load Meteor separately from Command line.  Is there any way to do that step from within WebStorm?  Or do I need to open up the Command Prompt every time I run my code?

Comment: Thanks Ethaan.  Tried that earlier, but I'm getting stuck on trying to figure out Nitrous.  Can't even get the preview to work.

Comment: Did you find a solution to this issue brendan?

Comment: @Brendan, hang in there. [A new Meteor for Windows installer is being built from scratch](https://github.com/meteor/windows-preview/issues/2#issuecomment-72339240).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need to run Vagrant or figure out Nitrous.io. Meteor and WebStorm work just fine on Windows. See the video at http://meteorpedia.com/read/Webstorm. You don't need to start `meteor` separately either.

Here's how to run the http://meteor.com/try example:

1. Install [Meteor for Windows](https://github.com/meteor/meteor/wiki/Preview-of-Meteor-on-Windows) if you haven't already. If you have, delete the folder `%USERPROFILE%\AppData\Local\.meteor` and install the latest preview again.
2. Start WebStorm
3. Create a new project, choose type Meteor.js app, then "default".
4. Run -> Run -> Edit configurations
5. Click the `+` to add a new configuration of type Meteor
6. Call it `simple-todos` for clarity (this is optional)
7. Click Run

Notice how Webstorm starts a console within the IDE, which shows the familiar Meteor startup sequence:

```
=> Started proxy.
=> Started MongoDB.
=> Started your app.

=> App running at: http://localhost:3000/
```

If you're prompted for any firewall permissions, make sure to allow all traffic from Node.js.

Since you created the project from WebStorm, files won't be named `simple-todos.*`, but rather `hello.*`. I've just [filed an issue about that](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/WEB-15026).

Also, the steps to create a configuration won't be necessary, thanks to [another issue that's been filed](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/WEB-14834).

Answer (score 0):

I used a virtualised solution to work with meteor on windows, for some reason the windows version of meteor don't work as expected, I got a lot of unexpected errors...

I suugest you to use vagrant with your WebStorm if you want to be on windows.

I made small video to show how it works with IntellijIdea and must be the same for WebStorm.

Here the video
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=woFUR1dMZ3g

Comment: The Meteor Windows preview works quite well actually, and many minor [issues are being ironed out on GitHub](https://github.com/meteor/windows-preview/issues). We need more testers to ensure Meteor runs flawlessly on Windows. Please don't discourage people from using Meteor on Windows by suggesting virtualized solutions. Thank you.

Comment: Dan, thanks for the note. I've at least got it up and running through using WebStorm. Definitely looking forward to a Windows release with faster build times. Trying to learn step-by-step and server restarts on each code change make it very tough. But it's great otherwise!